# Does the length of the first argument of socket.emit in socket.io affect latency?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm curious as to whether there is a difference, aside from readability between things like:

```
socket.emit('m','something');
```

and

```
socket.emit('chat message','something');
```

Would changing from the latter to the former lessen the amount of data sent significantly enough to justify the change in an application such as a chatroom, where messages like this are frequent?

Comment: Better to look for something else, it's not that your problem.

Comment: It would be so small that it isn't even worth talking about.  Generically speaking, latency would only be effected by your network, server load, or payload size.

Comment: So it definitely has nothing to do with clients disconnecting? I thought it might be, due to it happening more frequently when more users connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  [Latency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latency_(engineering)#Communication_latency) would not be effected by a small change in packet size.

It would consume slightly more overall bandwidth (if there were a ton of these packets and there is no packet padding in the transport), but bandwidth consumption is completely different than latency and latency would not be impacted by this small a difference in packet size.